# Closed curve $C^1$ but not $C^2$

Tags: geometry, continuity, curves

I need to find an exemple of closed curve that is $C^1$ but not $C^2$ in the dimension I want.

I thought of the curve $\gamma : [-1,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $\gamma(t)=\big(0,t^3\cdot \sin(\frac{1}{t})\big)$ and $\gamma(0)=(0,0)$.

I do not know if I am allowed to define it this way and if this segment is considered as a closed curve.

Comment: Bézier curves are $C_1$ continuous; Catmull-Rom curves are $C_2$ continuous. [C++ curve library](https://github.com/chen0040/cpp-spline)

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by a curve here. The graph of the function $t \mapsto t^3\sin(1/t) : [-1, 1] \to \Bbb{R}$ sounds like a good thing to start with: to make it into a closed curve you'll have to join the ends together. Your formula defines a "curve" whose image is an interval in the $y$-axis. You need to check the definitions that apply in your textbook or course notes, to see if your formula meets the requirements.

Comment: @RobArthan The curve is closed if the images of the interval's min and max are the same, here $f(-1)=f(1)$

Comment: If there are no other requirements on the notion of curve, then your answer looks OK to me assuming that $C_1$ and $C_2$ just refer to the specific function that you give to define the curve and not any intrinsic properties of the image of the curve.

Comment: There are also things like $|t|^3$ that are $C^1$ but not $C^2$ in $(0,0)$.

Comment: Try $f(x)=x^2$ for $x\gt 0$ and $f(x)=-x^2$ for x\le 0$

Answer (score 0):

One example is the boundary of a half-disk in the upper half plane, i.e. a line segment from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ along the $x$-axis, and then a half circle from $(1,0)$ to $(-1,0)$, passing through the point $(0,1)$. Formally, you can define this curve as
$$
\gamma(t) :=
\begin{cases}
(2t+1,0) & t \in [-1,0]\\
(\cos(\pi t),\sin(\pi t)) & t \in [0,1]
\end{cases}.
$$
Intuitively, it is clear that $\gamma$ is $C^1$ but not $C^2$, because of the angles of $\gamma$ at the points $(\pm 1,0)$. Of course this is not rigorous, but I hope the idea makes sense.